# ASP.NET rejected this request because the queue limit was exceeded

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis-7

When i run my website from IIS i got this error.

```
ASP.NET rejected this request because the queue limit was exceeded.
```

My users getting the error message:

```
This service is unavailable
```

Recycling the `application pool` solves the problem for some times only but problem occurred again within some hours. I exceed the `queue lenght` of `application poo`l by using this formula

```
available memory * processor * 10 / total number of application pool.
```

I got the result 40,000. So i set the `queue length` to 40,000 of application pool. But it didn't solve my problem. I update the `Ping maximum response time, shut down time limit and stratup time limit` and set all to 200. Problem didn't occur again but i am not sure it solve my problem or load decrease in my site. My website starts working normally now.

Can anybody know more about this error or can anybody suggest me the way how can i diagnose the problem, I am hoping this error will again occur in next Friday so i want to be well prepared to find the problem.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Do not try to fix this by making the queue longer - start fixing it by fixing the problem. A longer queue will only handle burst scenarios....

The problem is that your server is not keeping up, which is why the queue fills up. You get a lot of requests and you can not handle them. As I said - in a burst a longer queue helps, but at the end  you have to keep up.

Start profiling your code and making it more efficient, alternatively look where the bottleneck is (CPU, memory, discs) and add there - possibly adding more servers.

Comment: CPU consuming bellow 20% and over 5GB RAM is available on the server. Hard disk is also enough available, How can i know which part of code making the problem?

Comment: CPU says nothing - you can well have a CPU waiting for IO with all threads. 5GB memory says nothing either, unless you tell me it is 5gb FREE memory - you could well have an applicaiton needing more. Heck, I have a 48gb memory server here and it is too small. And if you as a programmer do not know how do use a profiler - time to look for a senior developer for baseline performance optimization. Performance Profilers (like the one included in - cough - VIsual Studio) are baseline knowledge for non-junior people. Start doing a proper analysis. What about your disc IO?

Comment: 5 GB is FREE memory, Thanks for help i am going to start profiling of my code.

Comment: Start checking your disc latency. I somehow get the idea you have a disc based problem - mostly because most peopel ignore disc speed and it comes back to bite them.